# Multicast NTP server/client

Tags: ntp, multicast

What I have here is an NTP server (on Linux Mint) and a client (likewise). Server is configured to send a multicast message across the LAN which clients receive and update their clocks - it was designed so to reduce network load.

The NTP server is, in turn, updating its own clock from a unicast NTP server of a higher level, also in the same LAN.
What does not  work is the receiving the multicast packet and updating clock on the client's side.

I am currently sniffing packets on the client machine and I can see multicasts coming. Using ntpdate -s on a client machine and pointing to the higher-level NTP in the same LAN works, i.e. the clock is updated.

I'm attaching configs for both Multicast server:

http://pastebin.com/wGK8Szqj

and client:

http://pastebin.com/HU8R8L0a

Here's proof that the Mcast packets reach the client:

[image]

I already tried running ntpd client with -Ab (accepting unauthenticated broadcasts), but that does not work either.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Two changes are required for this to work:

1. Remove the `server` definition as it's replaced by the `broadcastclient` entry
2. Remove the `nopeer` qualifier from the `restrict` statement. Otherwise the client cannot (will not) talk to the multicast server.

Here's a corrected sample client configuration file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

disable auth
broadcastclient

restrict -4  default    noquery nomodify notrap
restrict -6  default    noquery nomodify notrap
restrict     127.0.0.1
restrict     ::1
```